# flexbox gallery dynamically change div height as the image height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

i'm creating an application in react that has posts section and inside every post there is img tag, h1 tag and and p tag.

I don't know every image height because it changes dynamically, but they all have the same width.

I want the div that contains the image to dynamically change as the image height.
how can I do this?

I want the post structure to look like this:
[image: Images]
.

this is my code:

```css
.post {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: auto ;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: palevioletred;

    img {
        width: 300px;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    h1,p {
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    p {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
 <div className="post">
   <img src={this.props.image}/>
   <p>♥ {this.props.likes}</p>
   <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: As long as the containing element doesn't have a set height it should automatically adjust/expand to account for the image's height. Note the picture you show is probably done by using libraries like masonry where the elements are explicitly positioned

Answer (score 0):

The posts need to be wrapped in a flex container with fixed height that will flow these posts vertically.

Below I'm generating random posts with svgs as placeholders for the images associated with the posts:

```
[...Array(25)].map((elem, index) => this.renderPost(index))
```

In your real application you will certainly have a list of posts, just replace `[...Array(25)].map` by something like `posts.map`.

Then in the `renderPost`, replace the idx param by a post object and use the post values instead of the random values.

The svgs are used because when you set a viewBox on a svg it behaves as an image (has intrinsics dimensions). But they have nothing to do with the solution.

Just replace the svgs by the images you wanted.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  renderPost(idx) {
    const randomHeight = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 50;
    return (
      <div className="post">
        <svg viewBox={`0 0 150 ${randomHeight}`}><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/></svg>
        <p>♥ {Math.round(Math.random() * 100 + 1)}</p>
        <h1>title {idx + 1}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {[...Array(25)].map((elem, index) => this.renderPost(index))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 1600px;
}
.post {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: palevioletred;
    width: 150px;
    svg {
        width: 100%;
        background: #AAAAAA;
    }

    h1,p {
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    p {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: thank you for the help, i am super-new at react and doesn't know svg, do you have maybe any simpler way to do it? or help me implant this to my code?

Comment: The svgs are there only as placeholders for your images (because svg with viewBox has the same behavior as images with intrinsics dimensions). Use plain images instead and that should work the same. (and update the css rule targeting as well)

Comment: But if you post more of your code I may help you adapt this solution for your needs... Here I've just changed the minimum to build a working example. A list of posts samples could help.

Comment: I've added more details to the solution. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately, I still didn't understand... can you maybe help me with my code? here is the repo: https://github.com/lidorb94/instagram-ui
the Post component will be found in Feed folder

Comment: By looking at your code, I saw that Posts are wrapped in Feed, which is a div with the `container` className. As above, all you need to do is to add `flex-direction: column`, `flex-wrap: wrap` and set an heigth to allow the Posts to flow. I've renamed my previous `wrapper` class as `container`.so that you can refer to the css of this answer.